# Springboot How to query a many to many relationship

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many, entity

I have two entities lets call them Categories and Products. These two entities are mapped by a many to many relationship.

> My problem is that i am trying to get category information from products. Trying this results in empty categories.

This is my code :

**PersistenceEntity**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class PersistenceEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4056818895685613967L;
    // Instance Variables
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    protected Long id;
    @JsonIgnore
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected Date creationDate = new Date();

    ...Getters and Setters omitted for brevity

}
```

**Category**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Category extends PersistenceEntity{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String categoryName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean active;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String picture;

    @JsonIgnore
    private MetaData metadata;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "categories")
    private Set<Product> products;

        ...Getters and Setters omitted for brevity

 }
```

**Product**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products",uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "productCode")})
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Product extends PersistenceEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8727166810127029053L;

    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String name;

    private String productImageUrl;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="category_products", 
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="product_id", unique = false)}, 
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="category_id", unique = false)})
    private Set<Category> categories;


            ...Getters and Setters omitted for brevity

  }
```

**ProductServiceImplementation**

```
@Service
public class ProductService {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    public List<Product> getProductsByShopId( Long id) {
      List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
      productList = productRepository.findByShopId(id);
      return productList;
    }

    public Set<Long> getCategoryIds(List<Product> products){

        Set<Long> categoriesIDs = new HashSet<Long>();


        for (Product product : products) {
            product.getCategories().forEach(category -> {
                categoriesIDs.add(category.getId());
            });
        }

        return categoriesIDs;
    }

}
```

The problem is getting the categoryIds that are mapped to the list of products.

> **How can i get CategoryIds from Product. My getCategoryIds function returns empty always**

```
 public Set<Long> getCategoryIds(List<Product> products){

    Set<Long> categoriesIDs = new HashSet<Long>();


    for (Product product : products) {
        product.getCategories().forEach(category -> {
            categoriesIDs.add(category.getId());
        });
    }

    return categoriesIDs;
}
```

Comment: You already are. What's the problem?

Comment: getCategoryIds(List<Product> products) function doesnt return the iDs it  always comes back empty

Comment: That simply means that none of the products you're passing has any category. Check where these products come from.Check what the list contains. Check your database. Do some debugging.

Comment: Side note: why do you create a new ArrayList in getProductsByShopId?

Comment: You are right my problem was stale data in the database and also that new arrayList shouldnt be there

Comment: However on another not how do i persist data in the join table

Comment: By adding a category to the set of categories of a product.

Comment: I want to persist the mappings separately from persisting category or product information

Comment: OK. So what? How does that prevent you from adding a category to the set of a categories of a product?

Comment: The thing categories can be added seperately from products and also the same with products. However i want to create an endpoint to map a shopID with a categoryID directly maps to the joinTable and enters ids only.

Comment: So, find the category by its ID, then find the product by its ID (or the products by their shop ID), then add the category to the product(s). What's the concrete problem?

Comment: I think your solution will work